# How to switch an svg to another svg after clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have this sun svg image that switches the page to dark mode:

```
<svg onclick="myFunction()" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M12 3V5.25M18.364 5.63604L16.773 7.22703M21 12H18.75M18.364 18.364L16.773 16.773M12 18.75V21M7.22703 16.773L5.63604 18.364M5.25 12H3M7.22703 7.22703L5.63604 5.63604M15.75 12C15.75 14.0711 14.0711 15.75 12 15.75C9.92893 15.75 8.25 14.0711 8.25 12C8.25 9.92893 9.92893 8.25 12 8.25C14.0711 8.25 15.75 9.92893 15.75 12Z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
  </path>
</svg>
```

this is the JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

and this is some CSS:

```
.dark-mode {
  background: #333;
}

.dark-mode path {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

however, I want the svg itself to be switched, too, after clicking on it as a replacement. This is the other svg to be switched to, which is a moon svg image:

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M21.7519 15.0019C20.597 15.4839 19.3296 15.75 18 15.75C12.6152 15.75 8.25 11.3848 8.25 5.99999C8.25 4.67039 8.51614 3.40296 8.99806 2.24805C5.47566 3.71785 3 7.19481 3 11.25C3 16.6348 7.36522 21 12.75 21C16.8052 21 20.2821 18.5243 21.7519 15.0019Z" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
  </path>
</svg>
```

how can this be done, please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: Ikr, I really would like to add snippets to my questions and I have tried to do it before, but I use a touch device and when I click on the snippet button it says that the snippet editor doesn't support touch devices, so I'm really not able to do it, do you know any work around for touch devices?

Comment: No, that editor only accepts keyboard and mouse, some devices can be switched to mouse mode. At least you tried +1

Comment: Why not _also_ do this based on the `dark-mode` class? Just have both of the SVG in the document to begin with, one showing, one hidden using `display: none`. And then simply switch their visibility. `.darkmode .sun { display: none; } .darkmode .moon { display: block; }`

Comment: I've tried to do your solution but it didn't work, looks like something is wrong or missing in my code, could you please add it as an answer to the question with the entire code? A beginner here so would you excuse me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the paths as a dictionary and pass the `svg` into the `myFunction`, and update the `innerHTML` based on what `classList.toggle` returns:

```js
var lighting_mode_paths = {
  'moon': '<path d="M21.7519 15.0019C20.597 15.4839 19.3296 15.75 18 15.75C12.6152 15.75 8.25 11.3848 8.25 5.99999C8.25 4.67039 8.51614 3.40296 8.99806 2.24805C5.47566 3.71785 3 7.19481 3 11.25C3 16.6348 7.36522 21 12.75 21C16.8052 21 20.2821 18.5243 21.7519 15.0019Z" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>',
  'sun': '<path d="M12 3V5.25M18.364 5.63604L16.773 7.22703M21 12H18.75M18.364 18.364L16.773 16.773M12 18.75V21M7.22703 16.773L5.63604 18.364M5.25 12H3M7.22703 7.22703L5.63604 5.63604M15.75 12C15.75 14.0711 14.0711 15.75 12 15.75C9.92893 15.75 8.25 14.0711 8.25 12C8.25 9.92893 9.92893 8.25 12 8.25C14.0711 8.25 15.75 9.92893 15.75 12Z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>',
};

function myFunction(svg) {
  var element = document.body;
  
  if (element.classList.toggle('dark-mode')) {
    svg.innerHTML = lighting_mode_paths['moon'];
  } else {
    svg.innerHTML = lighting_mode_paths['sun'];
  }
}
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  background: #333;
}

.dark-mode path {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<svg onclick="myFunction(this)" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M12 3V5.25M18.364 5.63604L16.773 7.22703M21 12H18.75M18.364 18.364L16.773 16.773M12 18.75V21M7.22703 16.773L5.63604 18.364M5.25 12H3M7.22703 7.22703L5.63604 5.63604M15.75 12C15.75 14.0711 14.0711 15.75 12 15.75C9.92893 15.75 8.25 14.0711 8.25 12C8.25 9.92893 9.92893 8.25 12 8.25C14.0711 8.25 15.75 9.92893 15.75 12Z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
  </path>
</svg>
```

`element.classList.toggle` returns `true` if it has added the class to `element`, and returns `false` if it has removed the class from `element`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works just as expected. I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

No need for JavaScript, CSS can set the `d-path` (except Safari 17.4 - march 24)

For the Browser light/drark setting
use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

If you want a JavaScript solution, a native Web Component `<svg-celestial-body>` might be easier to work with

```js
customElements.define("svg-celestial-body", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.style.display = "inline-block";
    let stroke = "black";
    let fill = "gold";
    let width = 1;
    let d = "M22 15C21 16 19 16 18 16 13 16 8 11 8 6 8 4 8 4 9 2 6 4 3 7 3 11 3 17 7 21 13 21 17 21 20 19 22 15Z";
    let isLight = matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: light)").matches;
    if (this.hasAttribute("light") || this.hasAttribute("dark")){
      isLight = this.hasAttribute("light");    
    }
    if (isLight) {
      fill = "beige";
      width = 1.5;
      d = "m10 1v2m6 1-1 1m4 5h-2m-1 6-1-1m-5 2v2m-5-4-1 1m-1-6h-2m4-5-1-1m10 6c0 2-2 4-4 4-2 0-4-2-4-4 0-2 2-4 4-4 2 0 4 2 4 4z";
    }
    let path = `<path d="${d}" stroke="${stroke}" stroke-width="${width}" fill="${fill}" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>`;
    this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">`+path+`</svg>`;

  }
});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 110px;
}

path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

svg[light] {
  path {
    fill: gold;
    stroke-width: 1;
    d: path("m10 1v2m6 1-1 1m4 5h-2m-1 6-1-1m-5 2v2m-5-4-1 1m-1-6h-2m4-5-1-1m10 6c0 2-2 4-4 4-2 0-4-2-4-4 0-2 2-4 4-4 2 0 4 2 4 4z")
  }
}

svg[dark] {
  path {
    fill: beige;
    d: path("M22 15C21 16 19 16 18 16 13 16 8 11 8 6 8 4 8 4 9 2 6 4 3 7 3 11 3 17 7 21 13 21 17 21 20 19 22 15Z")
  }
}
```

```html
<svg light viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path/>
</svg>

<svg dark viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path/>
</svg>

<svg-celestial-body></svg-celestial-body>
<svg-celestial-body light></svg-celestial-body>
<svg-celestial-body dark></svg-celestial-body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work for me, unfortunately.